# How to import multiple modules into Elm REPL?

Tags: elm, read-eval-print-loop

When I run `elm repl` , I always have to import modules before looking at anything, including Main.  I want all of Main's imports also imported into the repl, without typing them out each time.  Is that possible?

The closest thing I can think of is like:  `head -n 5 src/Main.elm | tail -n 4 | elm repl` .  Which does get evaluated but then `elm repl` quits after.

Comment: Wouldn't simply copy and paste work?